# Multiple Maker with infoWindowContent and User's Geo Location

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to Add User's Geo Location in Google Map along with my other Markers. I have successfully added My Multiple markers, But i am not able to **Center/pan to the marker with user location**...

When the map loads, I want all my markers to show, but it should focus on user's geo location. Here is what i have done so far.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };
    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);
    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [
        ["Alpha Game One", 33.8008, -84.3894],
        ["Alpha Game Two", 33.8008, -84.3894]
    ];
    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content"><h3>Alpha Game One</h3><pThis is alpha Game one location here : <a href="#">View Locaion</a></div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content"><h3>Alpha Game Two</h3><p>This is alpha Game two location here : <a href="#">View Location</a></p></div>']
    ];
    var icons = [
        "https://cdn.mapsmarker.com/wp-content/plugins/leaflet-maps-marker-pro/leaflet-dist/images/marker.png",
        "https://cdn.mapsmarker.com/wp-content/plugins/leaflet-maps-marker-pro/leaflet-dist/images/marker.png"]
    var icons_length = icons.length;
    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        marker, i;
    var iconCounter = 0;
    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
    for (i = 0; i < icons_length; i++) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0],
            icon: icons[iconCounter]
        });
        // Allow each marker to have an info window
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function (event) {
        this.setZoom(3);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });
}
```

```css
#map_wrapper {
    height: 500px;
}
#map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map_wrapper">
  <div id="map_canvas" class="mapping"></div>
</div>
```

You can see, that it's working fine. But I want to add User's Geo Location and focus on user's geo location.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by focus? Open the info window or center / pan to the marker with the user location?

Comment: Hi, I mean , "Center/pan to the marker with user location.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [HTML5 GeoLocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) integrated into your code. The only change to your code except adding the geolocation functions was to take the `map` variable outside of the `initialize` function so that it is available in the `handleNoGeolocation` function.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

var map;

function initialize() {

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };
    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);
    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [
        ["Alpha Game One", 33, -84],
        ["Alpha Game Two", 32, -85]
    ];
    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content"><h3>Alpha Game One</h3><pThis is alpha Game one location here : <a href="#">View Locaion</a></div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content"><h3>Alpha Game Two</h3><p>This is alpha Game two location here : <a href="#">View Location</a></p></div>']
    ];
    var icons = [
        "https://cdn.mapsmarker.com/wp-content/plugins/leaflet-maps-marker-pro/leaflet-dist/images/marker.png",
        "https://cdn.mapsmarker.com/wp-content/plugins/leaflet-maps-marker-pro/leaflet-dist/images/marker.png"]
    var icons_length = icons.length;
    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        marker, i;
    var iconCounter = 0;
    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
    for (i = 0; i < icons_length; i++) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0],
            icon: icons[iconCounter]
        });
        // Allow each marker to have an info window
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function (event) {
        this.setZoom(3);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude);

            new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: pos,
                title: 'User location'
            });

            map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function () {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
    } else {
        var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
    }

    var options = {
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
        content: content
    };

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
    map.setCenter(options.position);
}
```

Comment: w00t, that worked, can i also change the default marker of google maps for user ??

Answer (score 1):

To get the users location you can use the [HTML5 GeoLocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)

To center the map on the user's location you can use

```
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()) or map.panTo(marker.getPosition())
```

So what you want to do is create a marker with the GeoLocation API and use the function described above.

Keep in mind though that the location accuracy of the user depends on the device of the user and the user always needs to give your site permission. So make sure you build in a exception for when the user does not give your site permission to their location.

Comment: Question is how can i integrate both in my 1 single map.

Comment: The link I provided for the HTML5 GeoLocation API already does this. If you have a basic understanding of javascript you should be able to understand how it works and implement it into your own site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet, may be a little help for you...
for detail please read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)...

```js
var map;

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
    } else {
        var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
    }

    var options = {
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-2.548926, 118.0148634),
        content: content
    };

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
    map.setCenter(options.position);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    mapOptions);

    // Try HTML5 geolocation
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                title: 'Your location !!!',
                animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
            });
            marker.setPosition(pos);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent(marker.getTitle());
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            map.setCenter(pos);
            map.setZoom(16);
        }, function () {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
    } else {
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<div id="map" style="width:600px; height:400px"></div>
```

Here's the [result](http://jsfiddle.net/ekojs/5tbsa633/1/embedded/result/)...
The result of run code didn't show because can't locate you position, so I include that in my jsfiddle in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ekojs/5tbsa633/1/)...